# Navigation bar expands, but does not collapse

Tags: css, laravel, bootstrap-4

I am making a navigation bar with bootstrap that isn't working. It starts collapsed. When a user clicks the burger menu, it expands. When the user clicks on the burger menu again, it remains expanded.

In console this happens:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-dark" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" 
aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
</div>
```

Which turns into

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse show" id="navbarSupportedContent">
</div>
```

When I click it again, this shows up:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapsing" id="navbarSupportedContent">
</div>
```

Whereafter it reverts back into step 2, not collapsing the div.
I am posting this question as the most relevant answer is on bootstrap-3.

I am using these scripts:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue, apparently I linked bootstrap twice, once via

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

And once via the regular scripts:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Removing the regular 3 scripts solved the issue.

Comment: For me the second bootstrap was in bundle.js.  The navbar expands and when trying to collapse you can see if flash - the event handler is being called twice, toggling it from open to closed and back to open again.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Unseptium here is the example for collapsible menu...

make sure you are using bootstrap js and popper js properly.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    
  </div>
</nav>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Even when I use your complete example, it still gives the same errors. This would include links. I am using laravel for refrence.

Comment: one more time remove your bootstrap js and use this js files --      

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Even when I replace the js bootstrap script and replace it with yours, it still doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: can you please share with me your live url so i will check whats the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the time you invested, the issue was that I linked bootstrap twice.

Answer (score -1):

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="./index.html">Expandable  Menu</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li>item 1</li>
          <li>item 2</li>
          <li>item 3</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```